# express how to access params from uri segment

Tags: node.js, express

My link is like this, I want to access number **16** on server

```
http://website.com/getItem/16
```

my routes **getIitem.js** like this

```js
let router = express.Router()
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params) // got empty object
    res.send('good') 
})
module.exports = router
```

my **app.js** is like this

```js
var getItem = require('./routes/getItem')
app.use('/getItem/:id', getItem)
module.exports = app
```

Problem: When I console.log reg.params, got an empty object

Comment: 1) Did you do `const router = express.Router()` at any point before you started calling router.get()? 2) did you actually use your router - eg `app.use(router)` ? Docs here might help debug: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router

Comment: those codes are straight out of express generator

Comment: Are you sure you actually spelled it `req` in your code? The code you provided will not produce this error.

Comment: @yen  `router = express.Router() `is sint the   getItem.js file

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `mergeParams` is true for your `router`.

```
...
let router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })
...
```

According express document:

> mergeParams : Preserve the req.params values from the parent router. If the parent
> and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take
> precedence.

Default value of this setting is false.